# Correct way to send an mp3 file in Python without losing any meta-data. (Base64 or otherwise) |AWS Lambda | S3 | Transcribe | Base64 |

Tags: python, base64, mp3, boto, amazon-transcribe

I'm trying to make a simple pipeline using AWS Transcribe, a speech to text service provided by Amazon. It takes as an input an mp3 or wav (among other formats). While trying to build a kind of API that could take an MP3 from a frontend, I constantly get`format not supported` errors such as `Unsupported audio format: matroska,webm`.

The Resulting mp3 file would work on Windows Media Player with correct audio but with a broken time index (showed 400 hours for a 10 second clip) and would not work on VLC at all. I believe I may be missing something fundamental about the base 64 encoding.

I believe the preceding headers that are usually passed such as `data:audio/mp3;base64` are for web UI parsing and not really stored into the resulting file. I've got the simplest variation of my code below. Another little addition is that I need to store the mp3 file on an S3 bucket for the pipeline to work

Client

```
with open(mp3_file_name, "rb") as h:
    m = base64.b64encode(h.read()).decode('utf-8')

request_body = {
   "mp3_base64": m
}

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = json.dumps(request_body))
```

Server

```
mp3_base64 = params.get('mp3_base64')
with open(tmp, "wb") as f:
  f.write(base64.b64decode(mp3_base64))

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
try:
  response = s3_client.upload_file(tmp, bucket, object_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being an encoding error from another library that was generating the audio files, the issue was not related to transcribe at all